# How to specify custom "ColorScheme" for "GradientScaleBoxWhisker" ChartElementFunction and Whiskers & Fences of BoxWhiskerChart?

Tags: plotting, color, charts

With [`BoxWhiskerChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxWhiskerChart.html) you can specify a gradient scale fill for the boxes using the [`ChartElementFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartElementFunction.html)and the `"GradientScaleBoxWhisker"` `ChartElementDataFunction`.

```
SeedRandom[456];
data = RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[#, .04], 20] & /@ {.1, .16};

BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Outliers", 
 ChartElementFunction -> ChartElementDataFunction["GradientScaleBoxWhisker", 
   "ColorScheme" -> "RoseColors"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The gradient fills over the range of the chart.  I would like it to fill over the first to third quartile range of each data series; `Red` at first quartile, `Orange` at second quartile, and `Green` at third quartile.

```
sc = Function[{x}, Blend[{{#1, Red}, {#2, Orange}, {#3, Green}}, x]] &[
    Sequence @@ #] & /@ (Quantile[#, {0.25, .5, 0.75}] & /@ data)
(* 
{Function[{x}, Blend[{{1.04715, Red}, {1.07836, Orange}, {1.14039, Green}}, x]], 
 Function[{x}, Blend[{{1.16097, Red}, {1.18109, Orange}, {1.19066, Green}}, x]]}
*)
```

Using `sc` in place of `"RoseColors"` errors out.

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Outliers", 
 ChartElementFunction -> ChartElementDataFunction["GradientScaleBoxWhisker", 
   "ColorScheme" -> sc]]
```

I think I would also need some form of `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` as well. However, this option is not valid for either `BoxWhiskerChart` nor `ChartElementDataFunction`.

I would also like to color the top whisker and fence `Green` and the bottom `Red`. The element styling only appears to allow one style for both.

Is there a way to get the gradient fill and whisker/fence styling I want by using `BoxWhiskerChart`?  I would prefer to use `BoxWhiskerChart` instead of drawing it all with `Graphics` so I have the options of all the element and outlier features of this function.

Comment: Maybe you need to compact your title:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your `sc` to define a list of colors as the value for  the `"ColorScheme"` option in a custom `ChartElementFunction`:

```
ClearAll[ceF];
ceF[cu_: Green, cl_: Red] := Module[{cs = Module[{qt = Quartiles@#2}, 
  (Function[{x}, Blend[{{#1, Red}, {#2, Orange}, {#3, Green}}, x]] & @@ qt) /@ 
    Subdivide[qt[[1]], qt[[-1]], 20]]}, 
   ChartElementDataFunction["GradientScaleBoxWhisker", "ColorScheme" -> cs][##] /. 
    Line[{x : {__List}, y : {__List}}] :> {cl, Line[x], cu, Line[y]}] &

BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Outliers", ChartElementFunction -> ceF[]]
```

[image]

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Outliers", ChartElementFunction ->
 ceF[Directive[Thick, Dashed, Purple], Directive[Thick, Brown]] ]
```

[image]